# AES-ECB encryption (Difference between Python Crypto.Cipher and openssl)

Tags: python, encryption, openssl, aes

i have a problem with encryption using python and openssl.

i wrote this small python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

obj = AES.new('Thisisakey123456', AES.MODE_ECB)
message = "Sample text....."
ciphertext = obj.encrypt(message)
print ciphertext
```

When i run the script with this command:

```
$ ./enc.py | base64
```

i get `E0lNh0wtSg9lxxKClBEITAo=` as a result.

If i do the same (or obviously it's not the same ;) ) in openssl i get another result:

```
$ echo -n "Sample text....." | openssl aes-128-ecb -k "Thisisakey123456" -nosalt -nopad | base64
yvNTGC+gwUK38uyJXIk/sQ==
```

What i am doing wrong?? i would expect the same base64 encoded string.

btw: i know ecb is bad, but i just play around, so it's no problem... ;)

Comment: Keep in mind that ECB is probably insecure (if you are interested in the details). Its only secure *if* the message is smaller that the block size, and there's only one message encrypted under the key. If you have a message that's larger than a block size, then you need to use CBC mode (or other similar) mode. And if message repeat, then each message needs a unique IV under the key.

Comment: Thanks, i'm aware of that. I'm not implementing something secure, just playing around with some stuff... Anyway, you can't mention it enough :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this command:

```
echo -n "Sample text....." | openssl aes-128-ecb -K 546869736973616b6579313233343536 -nopad | openssl base64
```

this explicitly specifies the key in [hexadecimals](http://www.asciitohex.com/). With `-k` the following "key" is actually a password, which is converted through an OpenSSL Password Based Key Derivation Function (PBKDF) called `EVP_BytesToKey` (using one iteration of SHA-1).

The result is `E0lNh0wtSg9lxxKClBEITA==`. This is not identical to `E0lNh0wtSg9lxxKClBEITAo=` but that's because Python adds a single newline character `\n` to the ciphertext, resulting in one extra byte to encode.

Comment: Just out of interest, which base64 encoder are you currently using? My Linux `base64` command seems to work well.

Comment: The IV argument is not needed (anymore) it seems. Which is good since ECB does not use any IV.

Comment: Thank you... one more thing learned today... :)
The base64 is not the problem i think. It's because the print command of python adds a newline and base64 encodes the newline too.

Comment: Ah, that would indeed explain it.